# How to use external script inside CircleCI build script

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

I would like to import logics from an external shell script as part of my CircleCI configuration and I'm looking for the "correct" (or best) way to do this.

Let's assume I have the following `config.yml` for CircleCI:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.5.3-node-browsers
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Compute some value
          command: |
            SOME_VALUE=$(foo.sh)
      - run:
          name: Reuse some value
          command: |
            echo "Hello" > /a/path/${SOME_VALUE}.txt
```

The overall idea is to wrap these steps into a CircleCI Orb and then have my build configuration reuse them from the Orb. But the `foo.sh` script cannot be packaged into the Orb itself, so I need some other way to make it accessible inside the build configuration.

So how I can include the `foo.sh` script (or any other script or executable) into my build process?

What I see so far (and why I don't think that's the best way to do it):

1. From the CircleCI documentation I don't see a way to include scripts like `foo.sh` directly as part of an Orb.
2. I could create a new Docker image, based upon `circleci/XXX`, include my script in that Docker image and call it directory. I don't really like the idea as the script has nothing to do with the Docker image it's based upon - I would just misuse Docker as transportation here.
3. I could `wget` the script from a public location, store it temporarily and then call it from within the running container that is executing the build script. But loading content from a public URL and then executing doesn't feel right (and either a typo or some malicious work could lead to me executing some foreign shell script with god knows what content).
4. I could clone some Git repository with the script inside to the local file system inside the running build container and then execute the script. Feels a little bit better than option (3).

Any ideas or best practices that I haven't thought of yet?

Answer (score 2):

> So how I can include the foo.sh script (or any other script or executable) into my build process?

You package it in the orb.

Here's an example in one of circle's maintained orbs:

https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/slack-orb/blob/48638f19e8b12170027cc55f06a3a924a8f8dc2d/src/commands/notify.yml#L111

```
      command: <<include(scripts/notify.sh)>>
```

references the script in https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/slack-orb/blob/48638f19e8b12170027cc55f06a3a924a8f8dc2d/src/scripts/notify.sh

Comment: How to execute that command with parameters?

Comment: @kylie.zoltan it's not run as a file that's executed (it's not chmod + ./script.sh or sh script.sh), so the short answer is you cant.     you'd set environment variables and use those instead of cmdline args.     you were to look at the compiled yml inside CCI, you'd see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

1. Works, a good example would be to use an S3 bucket for your scripts with hashes and you can wget them. check the hash against your hash saves in s3 so you know it's yours.
2. is also good. You can clone another repo once your in your circleci environment and use that repo as a source of your scripts. The VCS is nice to have on your scripts as a bonus.

Another option you can take advantage of the config being YAML and use HEREDOC to embed your script into the config.yml. use it in a run: that echos your HEREDOC to a file locally. This does make the config harder to read. Maybe YAML has "include" support so you can call another file to keep things neat in your config.yml.

Comment: downvote because trying to consume external scripts that you just push to a s3 bucket is....extremely bad version control.